# Problem adding <listener> to web.xml in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, websphere, listener

I use Eclipse with Websphere server .

I need to add a session listener  . I added the class SessionListener.java in the package net.test . When I add the < listener > tag to the web.xml file , I get the folowing error :

```
Distribution of configuration failed.  See log for details.
  Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServerCommunityEdition/repository/org/apache/geronimo/modules/geronimo-common/2.0.1/geronimo-common-2.0.1.jar
  java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServerCommunityEdition/repository/org/apache/geronimo/modules/geronimo-common/2.0.1/geronimo-common-2.0.1.jar
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:141)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.java:400)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:984)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.KernelDelegate.invokeKernel(KernelDelegate.java:890)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.KernelDelegate.invoke(KernelDelegate.java:551)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.AbstractDeployCommand.doDeploy(AbstractDeployCommand.java:116)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.DistributeCommand.run(DistributeCommand.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:810)
  Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServerCommunityEdition/repository/org/apache/geronimo/modules/geronimo-common/2.0.1/geronimo-common-2.0.1.jar
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:602)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:499)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:448)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.pathToURLs(LoaderHandler.java:762)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:162)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:259)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1490)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1723)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1932)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1856)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1743)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:363)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:231)
    ... 9 more
```

This is my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>odyssey</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
        <listener-class>net.testt.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>  

</web-app>
```

When I remove the  tag , everything works fine ... Please help ... I really need that listener to do the cleanup works to keep track of the current ONLINE USERS ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (nasty) bug in WASCE. It should have been `"file:///C:/Program Files/IBM/...."`. The `file://` is here the protocol which was missing due to the space in `Program Files`. The IBM guys should have quoted path names, but they apparently overlooked it.

To fix this problem, either install WASCE in a path without spaces, or upgrade to the latest version available.

Comment: haha.. interesting. How does it relate to the listener though?

Comment: It apparently (in)directly needs some stuff from geronimo-common JAR file.

Comment: That's rite .. the path is c:/program files/ibm .. After installing wasce in c:/ the error disappeared .. thnx BalusC